# after upgrading my glass to kitkat, my app that uses the camera API keeps breaking

Tags: android, camera, google-glass

I have an activity that uses the camera API to take pictures programmatically. After I upgraded my glass to Kitkat, this app has become very unstable.

After taking 3 pictures exactly, it breaks and I get the following error:
04-17 14:53:39.658: W/CameraBase(1658): mediaserver's remote binder Camera object died
04-17 14:53:39.666: W/CameraBase(1658): Camera service died!
04-17 14:53:39.713: E/Camera(1658): Error 100

After this happened, I tested my app in a glass that was not upgraded yet, and it doesn't break.
Anybody knows if there are some policies that may have been changed in the new version regarding the camera api?